# Running a Multi Scale network with Tensor Flow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to try to build a multi-scale CNN using tensorflow from the cifar10 code.

For what I understood I should take the output of the first conv layer and merge it with the output of the second conv layer to feed the first fully connected layer. Is that right? If yes, how to actually do this?

I have almost the same first layers as for the cifar10 except for the norm1 and the pool1 layers that are switched

```py
  # conv1
  with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 3, 64],
                                         stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(bias, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv1)

  # norm1
  norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(conv1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                    name='norm1')
  # pool1
  pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(norm1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                         padding='SAME', name='pool1')


  # conv2
  with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 64, 64],
                                         stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(norm1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(bias, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv2)

  # norm2
  norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(conv2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                    name='norm2')
  # pool2
  pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(norm2, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                         strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool2')
```

Then I try to merge the norm1 layer with the pool2 layer using concat.
Here's how I do this

```py
# local3
  with tf.variable_scope('local3') as scope:


    #concatenate tensors
    concat = tf.concat(2,[pool1,pool2])

    # Move everything into depth so we can perform a single matrix multiply.
    dim=1    
    for d in concat.get_shape()[1:].as_list():
      dim *= d
    reshape = tf.reshape(concat, [FLAGS.batch_size, dim])

    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[dim, 384],
                                          stddev=0.04, wd=0.004)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [384], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local3 = tf.nn.relu_layer(reshape, weights, biases, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(local3)
```

I'm not even sure that this is the right procedure because the loss is now 17 when in the single scale case I had the initial loss set around 3.
Is this common?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GuyCoder I changed the question according to your request. The problem is that I'm not even sure that this is the right procedure. If you can fix the code it should be perfect but I'm looking more for an hint on how to do it.

Comment: That's good. While I can not answer your question, now more people will at least look at it and you will get a much better chance at getting an answer. If you have not seen [ask] or the [tour] you should.

Comment: I am also learning TensorFlow but before jumping into TensorFlow I am taking the time to translate [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) to F# and watching videos like [Neural Networks Demystified](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlcnxUlrtek) to get a basic intro.

Comment: @GuyCoder thank you for sharing the videos. I'm running the network and in a day I will reach some results (I'm running on CPU). I will update the post as soon as I have some results.

Comment: I am just trying to help you get an answer even if I can not answer. The more people who come here and share, the more we all benefit. Also you can upvote comments even if they don't give any points; it makes it easier for others to know that the comment is of value.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by multi-scale CNN (and possibly link a paper), please?

Comment: @danijar sorry for my late reply, here, take a look. P. Sermanet and Y. LeCun. Traffic sign recognition with multi-scale convolutional
networks. In IJCNN, pages 2809–2813, 2011.